# Add SSL to web app built using aws eb cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, ebcli

I built a web app on top of aws elastic beanstalk cli. I'm trying to add a SSL certificate to the site to make it more secure. The documentation says "The simplest way to use HTTPS with an Elastic Beanstalk environment is to assign a server certificate to your environment's load balancer". However, I don't see my app on the  Elastic Beanstalk console although is is up and available to the public. Does anyone know how to use HTTPS with an Elastic Beanstalk environment and/or to assign a server certificate to my environment's load balancer (not sure how to access my env load balancer either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you choose the right region when you logged into the console? That would be the only reason you don't see the app. Once you choose the right region, you should see your application. You can add a cert by going to the Elastic Beanstalk console ==> configurations ==> Load balancer and Add Listener, choose 443, https and the cert. Just make sure to add port 443 and open traffic on that port in the load balancer's security group. This blog post explains the process in ABC simple, step-by-step manner:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/

Comment: You were correct, did not realize I had to change regions. I already own a google domain name, do you know if I would have to transfer it to Route 53? I don't want to lose my gmail with the domain which is why I am concerned with doing that.

Comment: You should be able to use a CNAME record, take a look at this guide:
https://colintoh.com/blog/map-custom-domain-to-elastic-beanstalk-application

Comment: Thank you, I've completed this step. But do I add the https and cert on aws side? Or the google domain side? That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: I this should work: can create an ACM cert in AWS, give your domain name and choose DNS validation, they will give you certain CNAME records to create. The procedure depends on your DNS provider. Once validated, you should be able to use this cert on your AWS Load balancer. your in can also bring your own cert too.